# Javascript : How to get the Windows id of Opener window in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i had open a link in newer window. Now the current window id become the id of the newer window. **Is their any way to find the window id of opener window from for a newer window, if it exist**

Answer (score -1):

You should go back and look at the [Chrome developer documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) that talks about the windowId property.

The current window is the window with the tab that **executed the script**, not the topmost window if a new one is opened.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html does not have information on how to get openers window id. Am trying to print the windowid in chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function callback) in a background script that is running, it prints the id of newly opened window. But i need the window id of opener window.. please help, thanks in advance

Comment: OK, to make sure I'm understanding what you want to do: 1) Print the ID of the old window 2) Open a new window 3) Print the ID of the newly opened window? If you have any current code, that would help as well so we can see the context.